# How to create a workflow state field programmatically?

Tags: 8

I have my custom entity created, workflow module installed and now I would like to create a workflow state field on my entity. I know I have to do it in the `src/Entity/MyEntity.php` class in my module, but where do I get all those field settings for this particular field type for the `BaseFieldDefinition::create` method?

I have somehow managed to put this field definition in my entity class:

```
$field['workflow'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('workflow')
  ->setLabel(t('Workflow'))
  ->setDescription('Workflow entity')
  ->setSetting('workflow_type', 'test_workflow');
```

But it does not add a field to my entity. Thanks.

EDIT: `test_workflow` is existing workflow.

Comment: I always do `drupal upe` after I change the code, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with entity_reference and target_type to be workflow, it should work like that. And with handler_settings you can set your type of workflow.